# Symlink Error: PHP Warning: symlink(): File exists

Tags: php

Good day,

Could someone please assist / advise as I am trying to create a symlink between the images folder in the public_html directory and the images folder in the App directory. When running the symlink file, the message displays: "Symlink process successfully completed", but I receive an error log stating:

`PHP Warning:  symlink(): File exists in /home/property/public_html/symlink.php on line 5`

The code that I am using in order to try and create the symlink are:

```
<?php

$targetFolder = '/home/property/app/images';
$linkFolder = '/home/property/public_html/images';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the error was caused in the public_html folder that already contained an "images" folder. After removing the images folder inside the public_html directory and executing the symlink script, the symlink was created successfully.

Comment: This was the case with me, Symlink will want to create the folder by itself

Answer (score 0):

The `symlink()` documentation states that this is the expected behaviour if an error happens: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php#refsect1-function.symlink-errors

Even though error supression is a double edged sword, you can probably use it here if you check for the output of `symlink()` in a similar fashion:

```php
if (@symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder)) { // The @ suppresses the error
    echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
} else {
    echo 'Symlink process failed';
    return 1; // You should probably exit with a non-zero status code if that is your whole script.
}
```

Alternatively

```php
// die() will run only if symlink() returns false
@symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder) || die('Symlink process failed');

// If we reach this point, die() didn't run thus symlink was successful
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
```

Comment: Hi Hunman. Thank you for your reply. I have tried to implement the suggested code, but received an error for the first suggestion: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/property/public_html/symlink.php on line 9` I  have also tried the alternative code, but received the echo: Symlink process failed. Could you perhaps please advise what could possible be the cause?

Comment: The syntax error was because I forgot a `)` before the `{`, I have edited the answer to fix it. From your original message "symlink(): File exists" I assume that a file or symlink with that name already exists. You could use `is_dir()` or `is_link()` to check if `$linkFolder` already exists or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the error was due to the public_html folder that already contained an "images" folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the previous installations symlink for SquirrelMail is linked to RoundCube. Unlinking/removing solved in my case:

```
root@www:~# ll /usr/share/squirrelmail 

/usr/share/squirrelmail -> /usr/share/roundcube/
```